# Why does the input variable change during my recursive calls even though it is not reassigned?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a recursive solution to the following Leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-i/256/complexity-analysis/2380/

It is simply to calculate `x^n`, where `x,n` are both `integers`.

```
def myPow(self, x: float, n: int) -> float:
        
        def myPow2(power_x,n): 
        
            if n ==1: 
                return power_x

            print(x)
            power_x = power_x*x
            return self.myPow(power_x,n-1)
        
        return myPow2(2,10)
```

My question is simple- for `print x` above, I am getting 2,4,16,256,etc..

But why is x changing? If I take the line `power_x = power_x*x` away, then `x prints as 2,2,2,2,2...` as expected. I don't understand why that line would change x? Isn't `x` always the input (2 in this case) - unless we reassign it, but here we don't reassign it?

Comment: `myPow2` calls `self.myPow` again with a different value for `x`…!?

Comment: It is hard to understand recursion at first. I suggest you look up "tail recursion" on this site, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion/37010#37010 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your function definition:

```
def myPow(self, x: float, n: int) -> float:
```

and now at your function call:

```
return self.myPow(power_x,n-1)
```

you are probably passing power_x to x every time you call the function.
My suggestion would be not to nest the definitions (if it's not required by the exercise) to increase readability and set myPow to

```
def myPow(self, power_x, x: float, n: int) -> float:
```